# Add a title to C3.js chart legend

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

I am using c3js and I'm still new to this chart framework. I need to set a title to the series legend of my chart. How can I do this? Do I need to use D3 to implement this? 
[image: I need something like this]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this mess:

```
var firstLegend = d3.select(".c3-legend-item");
var legendCon = d3.select(firstLegend.node().parentNode);
var legendY = parseInt(firstLegend.select('text').attr('y'));
legendCon
  .append('text')
  .text('Legend Title')
  .attr('y', legendY - 20);
```