# C3.js Dynamically add details to legend

Tags: angularjs, dynamic, legend, c3.js

I would like to ask whether it is possible to dynamically add text below legend, using C3.js and Angular. I have created a graph that looks like this:
[image]

This graph is part of a project that implements linear and polynomial regression.
As you can see, at the left edge of the graph I have managed to show the Rsquared value, using an older answer found in :[Add a title to C3.js chart legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28241553/add-a-title-to-c3-js-chart-legend)

Now what I want is to also display some other information about the graph, such as the array of coefficients used for every selected regression type and the equation formula, below Rsquared. Since the user will be able to choose different regression types, the coefficients length will vary accordingly. 
Is it possible to add these info dynamically, to come up with something like:

**Rsquared:** 0.1234567

**a:** 290.08505759457904

**b:** 10.349760852957772

.....{c:....d:...}

**Equation:** y=ax+b || y=ax+bx+c ||.....

My available data is in the following format:

coefficients [290.08505759457904,10.349760852957772]

equation {a:  290.08505759457904,

```
      b: 10.349760852957772}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What's the code that sets the Rsquared label? Can't you just add a line break and the rest of the text, like: `title: 'Rsquared: 0.1234567\na: 290.085047\n...`

Comment: As I mentioned, I have used the answer code from the link "Add a title to C3.js chart legend" provided above. I tried using '\n', '\r' but with no luck. In the end, instead of embedding all this information to the legend, I created a <div> that shows the info, when the graph is created, using ng-show etc. Thank you for your answer though! :)